# create-react-app build error "Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element."

Tags: create-react-app, postcss

I create a app using [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/) and am encountering an error when trying to build a production-optimized version `yarn build`:

```
> yarn build help
yarn run v1.9.4
$ react-scripts build help
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element.

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This is unfortunately not a very useful error. Googling around for it seems to turn-up stuff about [postcss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-selector-parser/issues/147) but I'm not sure exactly how that's related to create-react-app, or how to go about resolving the issue.

*Has anyone encountered similar issues before?*

---

Note that the app compiles fine in dev mode:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view note-app in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.54:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn build.
```

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem for some time now. Unable to find a solution.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem with the `electron-builder` plugin for Vue

Answer (score 2):

Error message 'Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element.' may suggest some syntax error of pseudo-classes in one of the CSS files imported.

For example:

```
**header nav li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}**
```

were wrote as:

```
**header nav li: last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

It indicates there's a syntax error in one of the css files imported in the project. For example - `//`

Answer (score 0):

There was index.css file and in this file I had this code

```css
.flex-col-center: {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  align-items: center !important;
}
.flex-row-center: {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  align-items: center !important;
}
```

I don't know what is bad in this code as it all seems good to me, but I removed it and it worked well.
Debugging method: I debugged by using bare minimum code in the app.js file of reactjs project